# Jquery Change event for Drop Down list not being called in Partial view inside Google maps infoview in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html, google-maps

On my ASP.NET MVC index.cshtml page I'm successfully loading a partial view into a google maps info window using ajax like so:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Map/BusForm/@bus.Id',
            success: function(data)
            {
                infoWindows["@bus.Id"].setContent(data);
            }
        });
```

Then in the partial view I have these form helpers to create drop down lists (this also works, the data is correctly populated and the form submits successfully).

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("BusForm", "Map", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "results",
    LoadingElementId = "loader"
}))
{
    <h4>Line:</h4>
    @*@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LineId, Model.GetLines(), "--Choose Train Line--")*@
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LineId, Model.GetLines(), "--Choose Train Line--", new { @class = "lineDDL" })
    <h4>Destination: </h4>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StationId, Model.GetStations(), "--Choose Destination--")
    <div id="loader" style="display:none">Loading</div>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

I want to make the values in the second drop down list dependent (cascade) from the first so I need to get the change event. So on Index.cshtml I have this script in the "Scripts Section" but it doesn't get called.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#LineId").on("change", function() 
        {
            console.log('change was called');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried creating event like this:     $(document).on('change', '#LineId', function(){console.log('change was called');});

Comment: Ah yup, that was it. Didn't actually see your comment but you're right haha.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, it was so simple.

I just changed

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#LineId").on("change", function() 
    {
        console.log('change was called');
    });
});
```

to

```
$(document).on("change", "#LineId", function() 
    {
        console.log('change was called');
    });
```

And now it works